# AppleScript - How to take row 1 and use as file name and row 2 for content to create json files

Tags: json, excel, applescript

I have a large amount of data (367 columns of two rows, but row 2 has a lot in it!) to export into json files for web display.

I'm trying to automate the process of saving each one as a .json file - ideally they need to be named Row 1 Value.json, and then contain the value of the corresponding cell in Row 2.

I've got this far in AppleScript, but it seems to fail at trying to get to the worksheet - I get an error saying "Can't get worksheet "HARDCODEJSON" of missing value." number -1728 from <> "HARDCODEJSON" of missing value

Any suggestions as to how to modify the AppleScript would be well received. I've altered the file paths but that's it.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set workbookName to POSIX file "/Users/myname/Documents/exportedstreams/AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx"
    set sheetName to "HARDCODEJSON"
    set filePath to POSIX file "/Users/myname/Documents/exportedstreams/"
    
    -- Open the workbook file directly
    set workbookFile to open file workbookName
    set workbookObj to workbook of workbookFile
    
    -- Get the range of data from the specified sheet
    set sheetObj to get worksheet sheetName of workbookObj
    set dataRange to value of used range of sheetObj
    
    -- Loop through each column in the data range
    repeat with columnIndex from 1 to count of columns of dataRange
        set fileName to item columnIndex of item 1 of dataRange
        set fileContent to item columnIndex of item 2 of dataRange
        
        -- Save the content as a JSON file
        set fileRef to open for access ((filePath as text) & fileName & ".json") with write permission
        set eof fileRef to 0
        write (fileContent as text) to fileRef
        close access fileRef
    end repeat
    
    -- Close the workbook file
    close workbookFile saving no
end tell
```

Comment: The script isn’t getting the workbook (the `missing value` bit), so check your variables to make sure they are getting set.  It doesn't look like you are writing JSON strings - are you really wanting JSON?

Comment: thanks @red_menace - 1. The variable 'set sheetName to "HARDCODEJSON" should then feed through to where it sets the sheetObj variable getting the worksheet. Maybe this is the bit that needs updating? 2. Yes I am writing json (but I appreciate it doesn't look like it) - in row 2 all of the values are in a json structure already.

Comment: Ah I think I've understood your comment better @red_menace. The missing value part is the workbookObj bit I guess so I need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Excel sometimes uses 'name' when it means 'path+name' so I changed your variable to be more explicit.

```
set wbPath to POSIX file "/Users/myname/Documents/exportedstreams/AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx"
set sheetName to "HARDCODEJSON"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open wbPath -- née workbookName
    
    set wbName to name of workbook 1
    --> "AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx"
    set wbObj to workbook wbName
    --> workbook "AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx"
    
    set sheetObj to worksheet sheetName of wbObj
    set dataRange to value of used range of sheetObj
    
end tell
```

Notes: wbPath is a file url, not an excel object — you can't ask excel for its properties (e.g. *workbook*, *worksheet*) because it doesn't have any. Hence, your *missing value* error. Once the file has been opened, and thus become an excel object (a workbook), you can access its *name* and *worksheet* properties.

On another note, near the top of your script, you use 'posix file' with your *filePath* variable. I'd leave it as a string unless you actually need to use the file reference. Later in the script you coerce it to text anyway so there really isn't a point.

```
set filePath to "/Users/myname/Documents/exportedstreams/"
```

Alternate approach: open the spreadsheet as a workbook

```
set wbPath to POSIX file "/Users/myname/Documents/exportedstreams/AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set wbObj to open workbook workbook file name wbPath
    --> workbook "AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx"
    
    -- returns…
    wbObj
    --> workbook "AllStreamsFlatFile.xlsx" of application "Microsoft Excel"
end tell
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks! Well explained too.